# Freeze position when object touches terrain

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unityscript

This script is attached to my trees. It should freeze the trees Y position and turn Kinematic to true when the tree touches the ground. Right now it freezes the trees as soon as the game is started (the trees don't fall to the ground). Originally the trees have isKinematic and FreezePositionY off.

```
function OnCollisionEnter(other:Collision) {
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Terrain") {
        Debug.Log("Object interacted with terrain on loading");
        rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do realize that your `RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY;` call won't do anything, right? You now merely get and discard the boolean value. You don't set anything there. And if something changes the kinematic settings, are there any other scripts you have that might be affecting it?

Comment: just to check: collisionObject is populated in the inspector with the terrain in your scene? and to build on Bart's comment, have a look at http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/569516/how-to-set-custom-rigidbodyconstraints.html as an example of how to use the rigidbodyconstraints

Comment: @Lefty I updated my code but it looks like the object with the script attached doesn't detect the terrain.

Comment: ok, most obvious possible issue would be the tag being mis-spelled (terrain and Terrain are different). Try putting a `Debug.Log` in before the `if` and see if it collides with _anything_. If not, checking the colliders on the object and terrain are setup correctly, not triggers etc. If you're using a `Terrain Collider` make sure it's got it's terrain data set etc.

Comment: @Lefty Somehow I solved the problem. Many thanks. How do I mark this question as answered if there is no answer but only comments?

Comment: You can't. It needs an actual answer to do that. If you have one, add it.